# Need Help Accessing AudioInputStream Outside of For Loop

Tags: java, scope

How do I declare/access the appendedFiles AudioInputStream data to write it to the disk outside of the for loop?  when i place the disk writing command in the for loop, it works nearly as intended, but outside is doesn't recognize appendedFiles.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;


public class WaveFileMerge
{
   public void waveFileMerge(String[] fileList) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {

       for(int x=0;x<fileList.length;x++){

           if(fileList[x] != null){

                AudioInputStream currentClip = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileList[x]));
                AudioInputStream blankAudio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\test\\dummy.wav"));



                AudioInputStream appendedFiles = new AudioInputStream( 
                                 new SequenceInputStream(currentClip, blankAudio),
                                 blankAudio.getFormat(), 
                                 blankAudio.getFrameLength() + currentClip.getFrameLength());


              }


      }

      AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles,AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
                                new File("C:\\test\\final.wav"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of [variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). Variables declared between a pair of curly braces (`{` and `}`) cannot be accessed outside those braces. So if you want to access `appendedFiles` outside the `for` loop, you have to declare it outside of that loop. You don't, however, have to use the variable as soon as you declare it. You can set it to null when you initialize and then use it later. For your code, this would look like:

```
AudioInputStream appendedFiles = null; //declare the variable outside the loop.
for(int x=0;x<fileList.length;x++){

       if(fileList[x] != null){

            AudioInputStream currentClip = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileList[x]));
            AudioInputStream blankAudio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\test\\dummy.wav"));



            appendedFiles = new AudioInputStream( 
                             new SequenceInputStream(currentClip, blankAudio),
                             blankAudio.getFormat(), 
                             blankAudio.getFrameLength() + currentClip.getFrameLength()); //set it to something within the loop


          }


  }

  AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles,AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
                            new File("C:\\test\\final.wav")); //you can still reference it outside the loop.
```

### Warning

You should be careful, however, that writing the file outside the loop really does what you intend. If you write outside the loop, then you will only write whatever the last value of `appendedFiles` was from the loop. This is probably not what you want (otherwise, why loop and create the other objects?).

### What you probably want

If you would rather use one loop to create the input streams, and then write them all, you need another loop. In this case, your code would create an array or a list of `AudioInputStream`s, which it would append to in the first loop, and then write them out in a separate loop afterwards. My guess is that this is what you want. This would look like the following code:

```
    SequenceInputStream streamForAppendedFiles = null;
    AudioInputStream blankAudio = null;
    long totalFrameLength = 0l;

    //loop through the files, adding the input streams for them together as we go. 
    for(int x=0;x<fileList.length;x++){
       if(fileList[x] != null){

            AudioInputStream currentClip = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileList[x]));
            blankAudio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\file\\with\\no\\audio.wav"));

            totalFrameLength+= currentClip.getFrameLength() + blankAudio.getFrameLength();

            SequenceInputStream currentClipPlusBlank = new SequenceInputStream(currentClip,blankAudio);

            if(streamForAppendedFiles==null){
                //first time through the loop, the stream with everything is just the current clip
                streamForAppendedFiles = currentClipPlusBlank;
            } else {
                //for subsequent loops, add the current stream to the running total. Think of this like +=.
                streamForAppendedFiles = new SequenceInputStream(streamForAppendedFiles,currentClipPlusBlank);
            }

          }
    }

    //convert the stream with everything to an audio stream
    AudioInputStream audioStreamAppendedFiles = new AudioInputStream( 
            streamForAppendedFiles,
            blankAudio.getFormat(), 
            totalFrameLength);

    //write the file.
    File finalFile = new File("C:\\test\\final.wav");
    AudioSystem.write(audioStreamAppendedFiles,AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,finalFile);
```

Comment: @user1244396 Actually, I had a bug in the second part which I've now fixed. I'm also now wondering what you really intended. Did you want your result to be several files which have blank audio appended to the end, or one audio file which has all the other files and several blank spaces in it? My second answer does the former, not the latter.

Comment: @user1244396 Also, thanking someone with a comment is generally discouraged on SO. Thanking with upvotes or marking something as the answer is the appropriate way to show appreciation :-) Give a quick read about [how to use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: the ultimate goal was to merge a bunch of individual wav files into one, long one.

Comment: @troy I modified the answer- now it provides an example of appending all the files into one long one as requested.